# ssh remote server on some port other than 22 without password

Tags: ssh, authentication

I am usually connecting to the remote server with

> ssh user@server.com -p 11000

and then giving the password each time for user. 
How should I avoid entering the password each time I connect using ssh ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**First**, put this in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config):

```
Host server
HostName server.com
Port 11000
User user
```

You will be able to `ssh server`, then type the password.

**Second**, check in `~/.ssh/` to see if you have files named `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub`. If not, you don't have any key set up, so you have to generate a pair using `ssh-keygen`. You can give the keys a password or not. The generated file `id_rsa.pub` should look like this:

> ssh-rsa lotsofrandomtext user@local

**Third**, ssh to the server, create the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if it doesn't exist. Then append the contents of the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` that you generated earlier here. This might mean copying the file contents to your clipboard, then opening `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in a text editor and pasting the thing.

Alternatively, use the command `ssh-copy-id server` (replace `server` with the name in `~/.ssh/config`). This will do the same thing as above. At times I have seen `ssh-copy-id` getting stuck, so I don't really like it.

You should now be able to ssh with just `ssh server`, unless you have chosen to protect your private key with a passphrase. Generally if you don't use a passphrase, you should protect your private key by other means (e.g. full disk encryption).

**Fourth** (only needed if you protect your private key with a passphrase), [put this in `~/.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106601/250):

```
start_ssh_agent() {
    # Try to use an existing agent
    save=~/.ssh-agent
    if [[ -e "$save" ]]
    then
        . "$save" > /dev/null
    fi
    # No existing agent, start a new one
    if [[ -z "$SSH_AGENT_PID" || ! -e "/proc/$SSH_AGENT_PID" ]]
    then
        ssh-agent > "$save"
        . "$save" > /dev/null
        ssh-add
    fi
}
start_ssh_agent
```

With this, you will only need to enter the passphrase once per computer boot.

Comment: The 'narrative' should also include a discussion of how to avoid typing that pesky passphrase all the time. :-) ssh-agent and/or keychain are possibilities to consider.

Comment: Also, if your username on the remote host is not the same as your username on the local host, you can add a `User user` line to `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: @Faheem That's nice, but I've never set up such thing so I don't think I'm in a position to instruct others about it :)

Comment: @FaheemMitha there you go :)

Comment: Hey, better late than never.

Answer (score 7):

Turn to [key-based authentication](http://www.laubenheimer.net/ssh-keys.shtml).

Comment: thank you for the suggestion . I had been looking at the forums but was having problem with the port(**11000** instead of **22** ). With `ssh -P 11000` I was able to copy with ssh . Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

As a supplement to phunehehe's answer, see the [Gentoo Linux Keychain Guide](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml) for a guide to [keychain](http://docs.funtoo.org/wiki/Keychain). keychain also uses [ssh-agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent). The ssh-agent daemon makes the passphrase available (it becomes unavailable when the ssh-agent daemon dies) but keychain `reuses an ssh-agent between logins, and optionally prompts for passphrases each time the user logs in`, to quote the guide.