# How to avoid being asked passphrase each time I push to Bitbucket

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I set up my ssh stuff with the help of [this guide](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+SSH+to+Access+your+Bitbucket+Repository), and it used to work well (I could run `hg push` without being asked for a passphrase). What could have happened between then and now, considering that I'm still using the same home directory.

```
$ cat .hg/hgrc 
[paths]
default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/tshepang/bloog

$ hg push
Enter passphrase for key '/home/wena/.ssh/id_rsa': 
pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/tshepang/bloog
searching for changes
...
```

Comment: Isn't creating a key without pass phrase just dedicated to one host an option? It worked for me on github

Answer (score 455, accepted):

You need to use an ssh agent.  Short answer: try

```
$ ssh-add
```

before pushing.  Supply your passphrase when asked.

If you aren't already running an ssh agent you will get the following message:

```
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

In that situation, you can start one and set your environment up thusly

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

Then repeat the `ssh-add` command.

It's worth taking a look at the [ssh agent manpage](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/ssh-agent.1).

Comment: What is the point of the `eval` could you just type `ssh-agent`?

Comment: It displays some commands that allow you to use it, and doesn't execute them for you; `eval` does the excuting.

Comment: Not related to the original question but if you keep having these issues on GitHub, Bitbucket etc, make sure you're using the git/ssh URL, not the http, which will keep asking for username+password.

Comment: And if you don't have a default key, or want to add multiples, `ssh-add /path/to/key`

Comment: thanks for the reply

Comment: still asking for the password after ssh-add and identity already added

Comment: you can add the line eval $(ssh-agent) to your .bashrc and it works next time if you open a shell again without typing this statement. Also you can skip ssh-add. Just login one time, add your pass-phrase, and the next time it will be remembered.

Comment: Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Answer (score 56):

A way to solve this is with `ssh-agent` and `ssh-add`:

```
$ exec ssh-agent bash
$ ssh-add
Enter passphrase for ~/.ssh/id_rsa:
```

After this the passphrase is saved for the current session. and won't be asked again.

Comment: Most people don't want to be bugged for their pass phrases at all.

Comment: @stefano, I'm on Centos and the problem is that I have repeat these steps each time I reconnect to ssh !

Comment: @connexo the whole point of a passphrase is to not persist it to where the private key resides ...

Answer (score 48):

Create (or edit if it exists) the following ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host *
    UseKeychain yes
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: But I'm using a different pair of keys for every service...

Comment: @connexo you can replace the wildcard asterisk with your individual host name and 'id_rsa' with your corresponding private key

Comment: I needed to add `IgnoreUnknown AddKeysToAgent,UseKeychain` just above `UseKeychain yes`.

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Bad configuration option: usekeychain"  on the "UseKeychain yes" line.

Comment: @m4l490n: it seems that the `UseKeychain` option was added in OpenSSH 7.1p2 (2016-02-28). Maybe you have a previous version.

http://www.openssh.com/txt/release-7.2

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: it works in addition of the option in consideRatio's comment. @m4l490n you can try as well with that option, I had the same error message without the option.

Comment: I'd like to add that this has saved my sanity regarding Git LFS, which otherwise asks for you to input your SSH key password for every LFS file in a push.

Answer (score 39):

I use [Keychain](http://www.funtoo.org/Keychain) for managing ssh keys. It is also available in Debian and so presumably Ubuntu with

```
apt-get install keychain
```

Here is the [Debian keychain package page](http://packages.qa.debian.org/k/keychain.html). As you can see, the project is not very active, but works for me. I also commented a bit about this in another answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10233/ssh-remote-server-on-some-port-other-than-22-without-password/10289#10289)

Comment: // , This worked for me. It's way better than ssh-agent, since I do not need to enter my ssh key password _every time I open a terminal_.

Comment: @NathanBasane are you saying that using keychain you don't need to enter the ssh key password every time you open a terminal? How do you configure that? because keychain keeps asking for the password every time I open the terminal, only the first time I open it after booting though, but still. I don't want to enter the passphrase every time.

Comment: @m4l490n No, if you are using keychain, you should not need to enter the ssh key password every time you open a terminal. But you do need to enter it once after booting. The passphrase isn't saved to disk - that would insecure.

Comment: For me, it asks every time I log in (I have a git repository + ssh keys in a remote server and every time I do a "git pull" I need to enter the passphrase)

Comment: @MartinThoma That looks wrong. Check that you have configured .ssh correctly. In particular, is your shell configured correctly? If it's still not working for you and you can't figure it out, you could ask a question.

Comment: What about on Windows?

Answer (score 8):

For convenience, the optimal method is a combination of the answers of [jmtd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket/12201#12201) and [Faheem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket/12248#12248).

Using `ssh-agent` alone means that a new instance of `ssh-agent` needs to be created for every new terminal you open. `keychain` when initialized will ask for the passphrase for the private key(s) and store it. That way your private key is password protected but you won't have to enter your password over and over again.

The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Using_SSH_Keys#ssh-agent) recommends initializing keychain from `/etc/profile.d/` or your shell profile, such as `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`. This has a disadvantage in that it intializes your keychain as soon as you open a terminal.

A more flexible approach is to combine `keychain` with a specific `tmux` session. So, in `.bash_profile`:

```
tsess=$(tmux ls 2>&1)

if [[ "${tsess%%:*}" = "secured" ]] && 
   [[ -f $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh ]]; then
    # start keychain
    /usr/bin/keychain -Q -q --nogui ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    . $HOME/.keychain/$HOSTNAME-sh
fi
```

...and then it is just a case of starting the secured `tmux` session as and when required (launched from a keybind):

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(pgrep tmux)
new="tmux -f $HOME/.tmux/conf new -s secured"
old="tmux attach -t secured -d"

if [[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ]]; then
    eval `ssh-agent`
    trap "kill $SSH_AGENT_PID" 0
fi

if [[ -z "$PID" ]]; then
    urxvtc -title "SSH" -e sh -c "${new}"
else
    urxvtc -title "SSH" -e sh -c "${old}"
fi

ssh-add
```

Now, your keychain will only be initialized once when you start that specific `tmux` session. As long as that session persists, you will be able to access those `ssh` keys and push to your remote repositories.

Comment: How would I get this to work on a remote machine? I modified the second script to check for $SSH_CLIENT and if it exists don't execute urxvtc, just tmux. That works, but the problem is the .bash_profile portion. When I first login to the box it says "server not found: Connection refused" which is the output of "tmux ls". Then, when I execute the second script, tmux either starts a new session or attaches to an existing one, but there is no keychain prompt. Then, when I exit the session, the keychain prompt is there waiting.

Comment: I've updated the answer to silence tmux output if there is no session.

Comment: Thank you, but that still didn't solve the issue with keychain. tmux creates the new session but goes straight to any empty prompt. Only when I exit from the tmux session do I see the keychain prompt asking for my passphrase.

Comment: I guess I should stop saying keychain, since keychain is only executed in .bash_profile. The issue is from executing ssh-add. Although, if I run ssh-add manually after creating the tmux session, it works.

Comment: Skip the second script and just start your secured tmux session from `.profile` - that way you'll get the prompt for keys as soon as you login.

Comment: // , Adding keychain to my `.profile` worked for me on a remote machine, @jonyamo. Perfect solution for this. Now I get asked my ssh-key password once on my first ssh login. However, if I do more ssh logins to that machine, I do not need to enter my ssh-key password. Let me know if you want to do more with this. `keychain` and the `ForwardAgent` directive can make security much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sshpass`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install sshpass
$ sshpass -p 'password' ssh username@server
```

You just need to add `sshpass -p yourpassphrase` before appending your usual `ssh` command.

Comment: That sounds like a really stupid idea. Wouldn't that make your password show up in clear text in your shell history?

Comment: Exactly, but are you not supposed to protect your session with a password as well?

Comment: Even if you do, how often do you have a colleague sitting next to you and helping you/learning from you?

Comment: @belka someone may steal your laptop/disc and learn your password from .bash_history.

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: I upvoted this. I'm am testing a suite of installation scripts that use SSH a lot. I create and destroy SSH key/pairs continuously.  I NEED zero interactivity. I don't care at all if someone sees their passphrases, because they are useless.  I'm sick of seeing cowardly down-votes by narrowed minded people who disapprove of people who "don't use computers the way I think they should".

Comment: @MartinBramwell finally someone that thinks like me. Computers are only tools, we have to figure out how to use them according to our needs!

Comment: I should mention that you could also have been downvoted for not actually answering the question. :-)  If I am not wrong SSHPASS only works with UID/PWD calls.  I did not succeed trying to get it to submit a passphrase for a private key.

Comment: If you don't care about the security of the passphrase and don't want to have to enter it, then don't bother adding it in the first place ... why do something pointless and unwanted and then search for a workaround?

Comment: @connexo - to prevent any command from appearing in history, prepend the command with a space. E.g. `<SPACE>echo Hello`. Pressing up to go to previous command -> it isn't there. You could then close that terminal window, so it is gone forever. Alternatively, clear the current terminal window (including scrollback) by entering: `clear && printf '\e[3J'`.