# Frequent command "template": remove parameter expansion escape characters

Tags: scripting, zsh, quoting

I find myself using a handful of long commands over and over again with slightly different arguments.  For example:

```
rsync -havu --progress --rsh='ssh -l mylogin' some.machine.somewhere:/some/path /some/local/path
```

I'd like to be able to easily insert that command at my `zsh` prompt, and then navigate the command line to make the necessary changes to paths, hosts, and logins.  I set up a zsh parameter:

```
FOO="rsync -havu --progress --rsh='ssh -l mylogin' some.machine.somewhere:/some/path /some/local/path"
```

Then I can expand `$FOO` at the prompt.  However, the expanded command has all its spaces and quotations escaped with backslashes.  Is there a way to make `zsh` not put the escape characters in the expansion?

I know I can search my history for similar commands and then edit those -- I'd still have to type the long thing out once in each new shell though.  I'm also open to other ways I could accomplish my purpose...  I could write a python script or something but that seems like a lot of overhead for a fairly simple task.

Comment: try `FOO=(rsync -havu --progress --rsh=\'ssh -l mylogin\' some.machine.somewhere:/so\
me/path /some/local/path)`

Comment: Using a function is the right answer. Furthermore, you should probably not need `--rsh`. It's rare to specify a username explicitly when connecting with ssh. Usually, you would define an alias with the right username in your `~/.ssh/config`. See [ssh remote server on some port other than 22 without password](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10233/10235#10235) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a function that takes parameters for the options you commonly change. You can put this in your ZSH config and execute it interactively. Here is an example:

```
myrsync() {
   username=$1
   srchost=$2
   srcpath=$3
   destpath=$4
   rsync -havu --progress --rsh="ssh -l $username" "${srchost}:${srcpath}" "$destpath"
}

myrsync mylogin some.machine.somewhere /some/path /some/local/path
```

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestions, everyone.  Giles, I somehow hadn't run across the .ssh/config option; I've set this up and it saves some typing.  Thanks for the tip.  I will likely create a function as suggested by jordanm and Giles, although one thing I like about using rsync from the prompt is keeping the syntax fresh in my memory for situations where I don't have my own configurations....  harish.venkat's suggestion is appealing but unfortunately did not work for me.